# Click Event in multiple column list view C# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Hey friends I have list view with 3 columns. I need to fire different events on each click in those column header. HOw can i do that? VS provides simple column click event, how can i use it for separate click event for those column headers.

Comment: HEY  friends I got the solution :) sorry to disturb. The Code is as follows:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to investigate the value of the `sender` parameter you are getting along with the event.

Comment: I think the `EventArgs` parameter would be more useful in this situation.

Comment: @JD Are you sure? How can you detect what header was clicked if you enable the column reordering feature?

Comment: Using RoutedEventArgs, I think I answered a similar question on here yesterday. e.OriginalSource